# How do we push changes to GitHub Wiki from new branch?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push changes to GitHub wiki. I cloned the wiki using

```
git clone https://repo_link.wiki.git
```

Inside `master` create a new branch named `Staging`, modified a file locally.
Then I could see the modification when I used

```
git status
```

Next, I did `git add .`

```
git commit -m "Modified file"

git push origin Staging
```

Received this message:

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 333 bytes | 333.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/guide.wiki.git
 * [new branch]      Staging -> Staging
```

However, I cannot see this branch or changes on GitHub and thus, I am not able to create pull request.
Can someone help me, why I am not able to create a pull request or see this newly created branch on git webpage?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know GitHub Wiki supported branches and Pull Requests. Can you point me to where you found the documentation for those features?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I just found this https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages and I am trying to research more about creating pull requests on GitHub wiki.

Comment: "Once you have cloned the wiki, you can add new files, edit existing ones, and commit your changes. You and your collaborators can create branches when working on wikis, but only changes pushed to the master branch will be made live and available to your readers.", from @Aura's link

Comment: So, instead of creating a new branch if I push my changes to wiki with Write access, does creator of this repo gets to approve or reject my changes? @DanielFarrell

Comment: if I understand (and I"m just going off that doc) the wiki only renders master.  You can use standard git process to express your diffs and push to master but it doesn't appear that you can get a rendered wiki on anything but master.  I'm not clear on whether or not you have a standard github repo lookin' interface for PRs and such.